# How come my ExecuteScalar isn't working?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to return the result as a string and I keep erring out at the cmd.ExecuteScalar()

Any suggestions?

```
    static public string GetScalar(string sql)
{
    string result = "";

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();

    try
    {
        result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        DBUtilExceptionHandler(ex, sql);

        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm passing the following sql statement into sql:

```
    select count(LeadListID) from LeadLists WHERE SalesPersonID = 1
AND LeadListDateCreated BETWEEN '9/1/11' AND '10/1/11 23:59:59'
```

which works fine as a query in Server Management Studio.

EDIT:
The method works, I was building my statement with errors. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what is the error / exception and where do you build your sql string?

Comment: What's the error? Perhaps your connection string is wrong or the calling application lacks authorization to make the call.

Comment: @BrokenGlass, thanks, I took another look at where I was building the statement and it had errors.

Comment: Given the narrow scope of your question combined with the fact that you solved it yourself using a part of the application not accessible to the readers, please delete your question.

Comment: @Barrett if you're not even going to reveal what *was* wrong, this question is not going to be helpful to any other visitors, and may as well be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar return an Object type. It executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query.

If you return a `count` you may need to cast the return value into an Integer

```
 counter = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Without the exact exception is hard to tell you what you did wrong, but for sure, I won't use the ToString().

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
int result = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

**EDIT**

As djacobson pointed out, it looks like the `GetScalar` method is being used for all scalar returns, in which case it would make more sense for the method to return type `object`, and for casting/conversion to take place in the calling method:

Change `GetScalar` method to return `object`:

```
public object GetScalar(string sql)
{
    //sql code

    //execute scalar return object
    return cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}
```

Handle casting and/or conversion from calling method:

```
int result = int.Parse(GetScalar("..."));
```

Comment: Obviously this is a pretty bad question in the first place, but notice that he's written the method as `GetScalar`. Despite using it to retrieve a count, it *could* be returning any single value, not just an integer. His code will return the string representation of whatever scalar value results from the passed-in SQL. Your code throws when that value is not an int. Not an improvement in the general case.

Comment: Good point. The method should return type object, and casting should take place after the value is returned.

Comment: Nesting function calls is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: @Steve Wellens: I'm not really sure what you mean. I was illustrating a point. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Broad generalizations about coding style are almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Do you mean a broad generalization like, "simple is usually better" or "comments are good" or "use meaningful variable names"?   Nested functions are usually bad: they are hard to read and harder to debug, Func1(Func2(Func3()));  What did Func2 return?

Comment: I really don't see any constructive purpose to your comment, and I don't think that applies universally either. It comes down to readability, and it's pretty clear what the code is doing. In this case, it's preference.